# Page content not showing on mobile devices

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I am using a responsive Wordpress theme, Nexus, and I am having issues when viewing the website from mobile devices. The post content is fine when viewing the website from a desktop but the main content disappears (as though font-color becomes transparent or is changed to white) but the space for the content is still present. This has been tested on Safari and Chrome for iOS7 (iPhone and iPad).

I have tried disabling any plugins that may be the cause of this problem but to no avail. The issue cannot be replicated when resizing the browser on a desktop, the site responds and adapts as it should without loosing any content, so I assume it may be something to do with the meta tag in use, but the header and footer content shows fine. Could it be something to do with the `page.php` ( the 'default template' )?

The meta tag currently in use is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

The website can be viewed at <del>www.cafestylespeedtraining.net</del>.

This is the `page.php` file:

```
<?php
$featured_image = false;

if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) :
    $featured_image = true;
?>
<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="post-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .post-thumbnail -->
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="page-wrap container">
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-wrap clearfix">
            <div id="content">
                <?php get_template_part( 'includes/breadcrumbs', 'index' ); ?>

                <div id="left-area">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <article class="entry-content clearfix">
                    <?php if ( ! $featured_image ) : ?>
                        <h1 class="main-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                        the_content();

                        wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'Nexus' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );
                    ?>
                    </article> <!-- .entry -->

                    <?php
                        if ( comments_open() && 'on' == et_get_option( 'nexus_show_pagescomments', 'false' ) )
                            comments_template( '', true );
                    ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>  <!-- end #left-area -->
            </div> <!-- #content -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- .main-content-wrap -->

        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/footer-banner', 'page' ); ?>
    </div> <!-- #main-content -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any other files, let me know and I will paste them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple CSS problem.

The bugging element is:

```
<h4 class="widgettitle">Book your Cafe Style Facilitator’s Boot Camp</h4>
```

You can check it by giving the element block the following style:

```
display: none;
```

Also you can emulate mobile behavior in Chrome Browser using

```
F12 -> settings -> overrides -> emulate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arkilesh, you are correct! At the time of writing this question I was downloading Xcode to use the Real Device emulator, at which point I discovered the element and have since applied the styles required so that it adapts correctly! I didn't know about the Chrome emulator but that will come in handy in the future - thanks!

This solved my issue and I would up vote your answer but I can't because I don't have enough rep!